# Batch encryption using a public GPG key

Tags: encryption, gpg

I've written a little script for my Clonezilla USB stick which will allow me to quickly back everything up without entering any options by simply running the script.

Next, I'd like to store my public GPG key on the stick and add some encryption to my backups like so:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -iname "*.gpg" | while read file ; do
    gpg --encrypt-using-key-file "/path/to/my/keyfile" "$file"
    rm "$file"
done
```

What is the way to properly encrypt files using a public GPG keyfile, ensuring that it doesn't prompt for user input? How would I actually do this?

Comment: You can use `gpg -r name "$file"` where name is your own user id (aka key's email address). It will not prompt for a password. BTW, I usually add the `--armor` and `--yes` options. I'd also rewrite your first line as `for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -iname "*.gpg"); do`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the target key in the keyring. I am not sure whether it is necessary that the target key is valid; better make it so.

You should use a config directory on the stick. With this directory being empty you import the key:

```
gpg --homedir /dir/on/stick --import /target/key.asc
```

This needs to be done just once. From your script you do this:

```
gpg --homedir /dir/on/stick --trust-model always --recipient 0x12345678 \
  --output /path/to/encrypted_file.gpg --encrypt /source/file
```

You may consider creating a signature for the file, too. But that would make the operation a bit more complicated.

Comment: It's using a `squashfs` container as its root filesystem. If I chroot into that fs and import the key before I create the filesystem, will it... just work™?

Comment: The file system should not matter.